# SDL Tridion MVP Summit 2013 Results

Tags: discussion

Every year winners of the [SDL Tridion Most Valued Professional Contributor award](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/mvp_award/index.aspx) gather and create SDL Tridion-related open source projects.

Here's a list of the projects the group started based on community feedback (via Linked-In survey, join [Ron Grisnich's Linked-In's SDL Tridion Professional group](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=47490&trk=my_groups-b-grp-v) to follow the discussion):

- **Content Manager Schema/Component Form Extension**: [Tridion Field Behavior Injection Framework](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-field-behavior-injection/)
- **Content Manager TBB testing**: [Tridion Templating Test Framework](https://github.com/DominicCronin/T-cubed)
- **Client-Side Content Delivery**: [Client-side Templating for Tridion](https://github.com/puntero/CT4T) (CT4T), not baked or fried--this is either "steamed" or "take-out"

We also have a follow-up to the Tridion Context Engine implementation example in the works using the [Context Engine Wrapper](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/TridionContextEngineWrapper), I believe.

Nice examples and thanks to the group. Leave comments, update this  announcement, or add answers to help community members *help* you continue to good work.

Tip: Borrowed from  [Robert Cartaino's post on the success of StackExchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/) and [Joel Splonsky's Lion announcement on Ask Different](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589), **please ask questions on these and other open source Tridion projects here on TRex**.

**Discussions, planning, and code all go on their respective repositories, but please ask your smart questions and answer here about these Tridion-related extensions.**